# React renders the wrong data when deleting the item in the middle of the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I've got a nested field arrays setup use `react-hook-form` [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-galileo-nkz71). Take note that my actual code is a bit more complex, but the issue is displayed here just the same.

[image]

The issue I have is that if I delete an item in the list, say, `ID: 2` in list `[{ID:1}, {ID:2}, {ID:3}]`, the result isn't `[{ID:1}, {ID:3}]`, but instead, `[{ID:1}, {ID:2}]`.

Here's the [official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-x7btr?file=/src/index.js:174-187), which gets nested fields array right.

Near as I can tell, the only difference is that my form relies on data that is retrieved from an API (in my example, handled by an `async` function) whereas the official example uses data that's already been initiated.

Looking at samples online, some make use of the `<Controller>` field, but that just gave me more issues (in my actual code), and upon testing (in Code Sandbox), doesn't really change the fact that deleting 2 doesn't shift the entire array up.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **should not** pass array index as `key` to each child in a list of children. Here is the problematic code:

```js
{fields.map((task, j) => {
  return (
    <Box key={j} padding={2} border={1}>
      {...}
    </Box>
  );
})}
```

When you run the code above, you'll have children with the corresponding data array like this

```
{ key: 0, task: { id: "1", freq: "d" },
{ key: 1, task: { id: "2", freq: "d" },
{ key: 2, task: { id: "3", freq: "d" },
```

If you delete the first item, in the next render, the data array will look like this

```
{ key: 0, task: { id: "2", freq: "d" },
{ key: 1, task: { id: "3", freq: "d" },
```

This is because the first item where `task.id = 1` was deleted, but the index of the array still starts from `0`, so in the end there is a mismatch between `key` and `task.id`.

The [best way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/9449426) to fix this problem is to use a unique ID directly from your model instead of array index as `key`:

```js
{fields.map((task, j) => {
  return (
    <Box key={task.id} padding={2} border={1}>
      {...}
    </Box>
  );
})}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64244731/react-hook-form-nested-fieldarray-deleting-item-in-the-middle-of-the-list-does]